# Set IIS environment variable through script

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core, iis, environment-variables, appcmd

I want to add/delete/edit IIS, asp.net core website environment variables in an automated way through appcmd/batch file or PowerShell script, not only one website's variable but on bulk operation. although I can do this one by using IIS UI

[image]

Although I can add environment variable by using appcmd

> appcmd.exe reset config "variable"
> -section:system.webServer/aspNetCore /+"environmentVariables.[name='foo',value='bar']"

I could not find a way for add/delete/update multiple websites environment values by just clicking single button instead of going each website's configuration setting to set multiple values, After that I can use that inline script in Azure DevOps pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write multiple powershell into a file and execute it. Here is an example for reference.

1. Create a file and named "xxx.ps1".
2. Write multiple powershell statements.

   ```
   Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Core Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/aspNetCore/environmentVariables" -name "." -value @{name='foo';value='bar'}


   Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Core Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/aspNetCore/environmentVariables" -name "." -value @{name='doc';value='qwe'}


   Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/aspNetCore/environmentVariables" -name "." -value @{name='foo';value='bar'}


   Write-Output ('Execute succeed')
   ```

   Edit and remove enironment value

   ```
   Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Core Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/aspNetCore/environmentVariables/environmentVariable[@name='foo' and @value='bar']" -name "name" -value "foo2"


   Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Core Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/aspNetCore/environmentVariables/environmentVariable[@name='foo' and @value='bar']" -name "value" -value "bar2"


   Remove-WebConfigurationProperty  -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Core Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/aspNetCore/environmentVariables" -name "." -AtElement @{name='foo1';value='bar1'}
   ```
3. Open powershell to execute the file(file's path + name).

   ```
   PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> & "D:\floder1\xxx.ps1"
   ```

Comment: that's grea,t how I can remove/edit already added environment values ?

Comment: Excellent, now just only last things , how to edited values ?

Comment: I added the edit and remove statement at same time. Are you missing it?

Comment: Perfect, Excellent, now it works with all curd operations THANKS